# Why my LSTM layer behaves like a Dense layer?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to train a simple RNN:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as k
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K

#MODEL
model = k.Sequential([
    k.layers.Input(batch_input_shape=[30, 1, 1]),
    k.layers.LSTM(16),
    
    k.layers.Dense(1, activation = k.activations.relu),
])

model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss='mse')

history = model.fit(x = X_train, y = y_train, epochs=20, validation_data = (X_val, y_val), batch_size = 30, shuffle = False)
```

X_train is a 1D numpy.ndarray that contains sequence made of observation of type H0 or H1 (H0 is a gaussian of mean = 0 and std = 1, H1 is a gaussian of mean = 3 and std = 1).

I construct a sequence of 30 observation and on a random time, we pass from hypothesis H0 to H1 (I set batch_size = 30 because I want to reset the state of the LSTM layer after every sequence but I don't know if it's a legit solution).

I want to detect the change time H0 -> H1 the quickest possible.

y_train is a 1D numpy.ndarray that contains 0 if the observation of type H0, the delay from change time + 1 if the observation is of type H1.

For example:

If change_time = 4

I want as output: [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4, etc...]

but my RNN displays this: [0,0,0,0,8.674135, 8.674131, etc...]

Seems that my model doesn't have any memory and I dont' know why...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are suppose to use a sequence with seq_len>1.
The shape in lstm is (batch_size,seq_len,embed_dim) and you have the batch_size of 30 but the seq_len is just 1. the rnn is capable to memorize through the seq_len, so if your seq_len is just 1, iT wont memorize anything.

Comment: ok but now i have a question...
If I set seq_len = 30 will I have 30 outputs?
I would like the RNN express a decision for each observation of the sequence.

Comment: You can have only 1 output, it depends on how you set